# Touch and Multitouch events android

Tags: android

Consider a relative layout with three buttons of variable sizes with no anchoring arguments resulting in all being drawn at the top-left corner of the screen. Consider a single physical touch event being generated. Which of these buttons will see this event? If that all three have registered as onTouch listeners. How is the process behind this behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RelativeLayout` creates a hierarchy between elements inside of it. The item you put to the lowest line will be on top of all others. And when you click, its onClick method will be called. For example you have two buttons inside of RelativeLayout like:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_a"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="You won't see this" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_b"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="You will see this" />
```

And let's say your Java code is:

```
findViewById(R.id.button_a).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button A clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
findViewById(R.id.button_b).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Button B clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

In this case, you will always see the `Button B clicked` Toast on the screen, when you tap on these buttons.